# How to check if Random Forest model performed better than chance? (T-Test)

Tags: r

I perform 15-fold cross validation on random forest. Like this:

```
trainControl = trainControl(method="cv", number = 15, search = "random", savePredictions = T)



tuningGrid <- expand.grid(mtry=c(2,4,6,8))


model = train(Classification~., data=data, method="rf", trControl = trainControl,
              tuneGrid = tuningGrid, ntree = 25)

model
```

How can I use T-Test to show that the model performs better than chance based on the 15 accuracies?

I don't know what to put for x in t.test

Comment: It is not really clear what you mean by "better than chance". Normally you would specify a random process to generate predictions, from which you could generate a distribution of accuracies.

Comment: scramble (permute) the response variable, re-run your system, and see whether the accuracies with the real data are sig better than those with the scrambled data

Comment: Impossible to provide meaningful help unless you provide data. But this package might be relevant: [crtests](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/crtests/vignettes/overview.html).